# How can I clear the values in System.Azure.EventHubs.EventDataBatch in c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am using System.Azure.EventHubs.EventDataBatch to send a batch of events to the Azure Event Hub.

Once a batch is sent successfully, I would like to clear the event collection and then add new events to the event hub in order to send the next batch.

As EventDataBatch is a List of events, I expected there would be a Clear() function that will allow one to clear the collection. But unfortunately there isnt any. Does anyone know a clean way to achieve this?

Alternatively, I am thinking to dispose the current EventDataBatch and then create a new EventDataBatch using EventHubClient.CreateBatch():

```
var myEventBatch = eventHubClient.CreateBatch();
foreach(var message in messages)
{
    if(!myEventBatch.TryAdd(message))
    {
       await eventHubClient.SendAsync(myEventBatch).ConfigureAwait(false);   
       //myEventBatch.Clear();
       //myEventBatch = eventHubClient.CreateBatch();
       myEventBatch = new EventDataBatch(256000);
       myEventBatch.TryAdd(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. You're supposed to create a new instance using the EventHubClient.CreateBatch Method

Comment: @PeterBons I tried using CreateBatch function and assigning the result to my existing eventBatch variable. But it still contains old values. I am now doing myEventBatch = new EventBatch(256000); to renew the collection for next batch. is there a cleaner way to do this? This doesnt look too elegant.

Comment: Can you post that code

Comment: @PeterBons Hi peter, Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with my code.

Comment: @sajid hey did you get any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the dispose method in EventDataBatch.cs

[EventDataBatch.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/src/EventDataBatch.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `using` as EventDataBatch is IDisposable. This will take care of disposing the EventDataBatch object.

```
using (EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync())
```